# Best way to impute multiple columns NaN values with their mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm still new to Python

I need to write a function that imputes the NaN values of 2+ df columns with their mean.
I've tried several ways that work on the single column but don't work when combined.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

example = {'one':[1,2,3,np.nan],
           'two':[np.nan,2,3,np.nan],
           'three':[1,2,3,4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(example)
```

What I need is to impute NaN values with the mean of the series.

I've already tried:

- Calculating the mean of each column, then filling the NaN values with the calculated mean. It works but seems that It can't be automated.

```
df['one'] = df['one'].fillna(df['one].mean(), inplace=True)
```

- Imputing every single column with sklearn.SimpleImputer, but even if I reshape the fit and transformed array, can't find a way to automate to multiple columns.

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
SI = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')

X = np.array(df['one'])
SI.fit_transform(X.reshape(-1,1)
```

Could you help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If need replace `NaN`s in all columns (and all columns are numeric):

```
df = df.fillna(df.mean())
print (df)
   one  two  three
0  1.0  2.5      1
1  2.0  2.0      2
2  3.0  3.0      3
3  2.0  2.5      4
```

If need specify columns by names in list:

```
c = ['one','two']
df[c] = df[c].fillna(df[c].mean())
```

Or if need replace only numeric columns:

```
c = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
df[c] = df[c].fillna(df[c].mean())
```